# Flatten tuples when nested in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

As an output from a function, I get tuples in either the form a and b as shown below:

```
a = ((x, y), z)
b = (x, y)
```

I would like to flatten the nested form to be as follows:

```
a = (x, y, z)
```

This will always result in me having a tuple which is one layer deep, regardless of what I get as a return from my function.

What is the quickest and most efficient way to do this in Python 3?

Comment: How about simply `a = (*(x, y), z)`

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/5763413)?

Comment: Why not return (x, y, z) from the function or is it not yours?

Comment: Function isn't mine

Answer (score 1):

You could try to unpack the tuple and catch any `TypeError`'s:

```
def flatten(a):
    try:
        (x, y), z = a
        return x, y, z
    except TypeError:
        return a

print(flatten(((1, 2), 3)))  # (1, 2, 3)
print(flatten((1, 2)))  # (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` with `tuple()`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain

a = (("x", "y"), "z")
b = ("x", "y")

for i in [a, b]:
    print(tuple(chain.from_iterable(i)))
```

**Output:**

```
('x', 'y', 'z')
('x', 'y')
```

Comment: Try this with tuples of integers, for example ;)

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Thanks. I just used OP's sample thinking it might be `string`